# Yii2 Active Record: The best way to display related records

Tags: yii, yii2

I have two tables: **record**, **user** and a junction table **record_user**. I display the records, which are related to the logged user, using the Active Record.

In the model User I have the following functions:

```
public function getRecordUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RecordUser::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getRecords()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Record::className(), ['id' => 'record_id'])
        ->via('recordUsers');
}
```

See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#junction-table

In the model RecordSearch I define the query for the Active Data Provider:

```
public function search($params)
{

// The Object with all records, to which has the user access (the id of the user is in the junction table record_user).
$loggedUserRecords = YiiUser::findOne(Yii::$app->user->identity->id)->records;

// From the object is extracted an array with ids.
$loggedUserRecordsIds = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn($loggedUserRecords, 'id');

// The ids are used to filter the Record object.
$query = Record::find()->filterWhere(['id' => $loggedUserRecordsIds]);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
...
```

The code works as expected. But I would like to know, if there is a more direct way to display the related records, without the extraction of ids from the object.

Comment: Why don't you just add the createdBy, updatedBy Columns to your Record Model and Table? Then you just have to query `filterWhere['createdBy' => $user_id]` ?

Comment: The records are administered only by admin, who has access to all records (in backend). The admin decides who should see which records (in frontend). In my tables I have also fields created_by, updated_by, etc., but these fields have no use in this case. The code in the question is simplyfied and rewritten to be easily understandable.

Comment: I have forgotten to mention, that to one record may have access 0-n users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess RecordSearch has this relations

```
public function getRecordUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RecordUser::className(), ['record_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
    ->via('recordUsers');
}
```

Or

```
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])->viaTable('recordUsers', ['record_id' => 'id']);
}
```

then you should be able to check query something like:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Record::find()->joinWith(['users'])->where(['user_id'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->id]),
]);
```

if i didn't make a mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly. I use now: $query = Record::find()->joinWith(['users'])->where(['user_id'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);

Comment: if i think correctly you can also just try to join to the recordUsers table and add the condition there. which would take one table less to query.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by BHoft the fastest and most simple way is probably the following.

Model Record:

```
public function getRecordUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RecordUser::className(), ['record_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Model RecordSearch:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Record::find()->joinWith(['recordUsers'])->where(['user_id'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->id]),
]);
```